# Service based database c# foreign keys

Tags: c#, database, foreign-keys

I have a problem when implementing a foreign key in my database. It keeps telling me the error:

SQL71501 :: Foreign Key: [dbo].[FK_Purchase_Product] has an unresolved reference to Column [dbo].[Purchase].[ProductID].
SQL71501 :: Foreign Key: [dbo].[FK_Purchase_Product] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[Product].
SQL71501 :: Foreign Key: [dbo].[FK_Purchase_Product] has an unresolved reference to Column [dbo].[Product].[ProductID].

I am trying to get the primary key from the table Product and set is as a foreign key in the table Purchases.
Does anyone know what this is about pls? Thanks

[Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGvQ8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare column ProductID in the table?
you can look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp 
Its seems you have missed the column, from the code in the image screenshot.